# Consuming SOAP API in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, soap

I am trying to consume a SOAP API. I am have a xml in string format like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:int="http://integration.gwclient.smallsystems.cma.se/" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <int:send>
            <message>
                
                <msgReceiver>SYSTEM22XXXX</msgReceiver>
                <msgSender>SENDER22XXXX</msgSender>
                <msgType>pacs.002.001.10</msgType>
                <msgUserReference>FT1331669663</msgUserReference>
                <format>MX</format>
            <block4></block4></message>
        </int:send>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I have a Model class Message.

This is code I am using as of now:

```
(Response) webServiceTemplate
      .marshalSendAndReceive("soap-server",request);
```

Problem is I am not able to convert this String to Object of Message Class. How can we send request to SOAP in this case.

Comment: Which String? You should create a `Message` and JAXB (or whatever marshaller you use) will convert it to a soap message.

Comment: Which String-XML String I have added in my question. Problem is MarshalSendAndReceive expects an object of Message Class. The XML String i am getting I am not able convert that into Object of Message Class.

Comment: Basically I am asking how can we send XML string using webservicetemplate without converting it into object first.

Comment: Then why use a web service framework? Spring Webservices will add the soap envelope etc. so you need th plain message only . Why have the string instead of the objects.

Comment: Why have the string--- Actually its like how our architecture is designed so that we can handle any type of message our system will send me string only. When you say you need plain message only you mean that I should ask them to just send me XML inside <message> tag rest will be taken care by webservicetemplate???

Comment: Yes. Hmm a stringly typed system, not sure if that is something I would like to work on. If you are only relaying things don't use the web service template just use a regular http client and pass the message along.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229537/discussion-between-rishabh-and-m-deinum).